# Render a react component dynamically on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to render a react component dynamically, basically when user click SubComponent I need to run some logic and display another react component inside Component.

How to do that?

```js
const getViewer = (type) => {
  let node = null
  switch (type) {
    case 'image':
      node = (
        <ImageViewer/>
      )
      return node
    case 'video':
      node = (
        <VideoViewer/>
      )
      return node
    default:
      return null
  }
}

const handlerOnClick = () =>{
  // TODO
  getViewer('image')

}

export const Component = () =>
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <SubComponent onClick={handlerOnClick} />
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried conditional inline rendering? https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: could you provide me an example

Comment: Try adding a statefull variable "showViewer" to your initial state, then onClick change the state to true. Conditionally render it based on the state like in the docs. Can't write up an example cause i'm at work right now, but that should be a good start. Please let me know if you have any questions.